# Menu Scroller not working properly in Extjs

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, layout

I am trying to create scrollable menu in ExtJs

Problems I am facing:

1. Scroller on first click of menu button does not work (it seems to work when scrollable: false)
2. Next time when clicked on menu.. the menu no more overflows..

[Fiddle showcasing the problem](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hj5)

Also,

Required behavior:

[image: This is the behavior I am trying to replicate:]

Kindly chip in if any one got any ideas or faced similar situation

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had, and when I wrapped the menu into a container and set the height and the scroller on the container, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know question is regarding menu scroll but As per that your required behaviour you can use [`panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html) as overlay and you can use [`grid`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html) inside of panel with [`checkboxmodel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel.html).

You need to use [`showBy()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-showBy) method on setting button click.

Screenshot with overlay panel for multiple button click:

[image]

---

In this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2hk0), I have created a demo using `panel` and `grid`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        //Common button click on setting button
        function onButtonClick(btn, e) {
            //If menu is alredy created for that button no need to create directly show or hide
            var myMenu = btn.myMenu;

            //If menu is not create then need to create
            if (!myMenu) {
                myMenu = btn.myMenu = Ext.create({
                    xtype: 'custommenu',
                    title: btn.getText()
                });
            }
            myMenu.isHidden() ? myMenu.showBy(btn, "bl") : myMenu.hide();
        }

        //Define common store for grid menu
        Ext.define('MenuStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.menustore',
            fields: ['text'],
            data: (() => {
                let data = [];
                for (let i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
                    data.push({
                        text: String.fromCharCode(i)
                    })
                }
                return data;
            })()
        })

        Ext.define('CustomMenuOverlay', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            xtype: 'custommenu',
            hidden: true,
            tools: [{
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-download'
            }, {
                type: 'refresh'
            }, {
                type: 'gear'
            }],
            width: 170,
            maxHeight: 200,
            floating: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                flex: 1,
                width: '100%',
                height: 200,
                selModel: {
                    checkOnly: false,
                    mode: 'SIMPLE'
                },
                selType: 'checkboxmodel',
                store: {
                    type: 'menustore'
                },
                columns: [{
                    dataIndex: 'text',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            }],

            bbar: [{
                text: 'Apply',
                width: '100%',
                itemId: 'apply',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    //On appy button click you put your logic whatever you need
                    //You can get menu using up selector with {custommenu}
                    var myMenu = btn.up('custommenu');
                    myMenu.hide();
                    console.log(myMenu.down('grid').getSelection())
                }
            }]
        });

        //create grid panel
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Support',
            store: {
                fields: ['firstName', 'Surname'],
                data: [{
                    Rank: 30,
                    firstName: 'Mihir',
                    Surname: "Kothari",
                    FullName: "Z Kothari Mihir"
                }, {
                    Rank: 20,
                    firstName: 'Parv',
                    Surname: "Kothari",
                    FullName: "X Kothari Parv"
                }, {
                    Rank: 10,
                    firstName: 'Reena',
                    Surname: "Kothari",
                    FullName: "Y Kothari Reena"
                }]
            },

            columns: [{
                text: 'Surname',
                dataIndex: 'Surname'
            }, {
                text: 'FirstName',
                dataIndex: 'firstName'
            }, {
                text: 'Rank',
                dataIndex: 'Rank'
            }],

            bbar: [{
                text: 'settings',
                handler: onButtonClick
            }, '->', {
                text: 'settings1',
                handler: onButtonClick
            }, '->', {
                text: 'settings2',
                handler: onButtonClick
            }, '->', {
                text: 'settings3',
                handler: onButtonClick
            }, '->'],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply @N.Jadhav.. although we can achieve it using the way you just mentioned.. but it would be too much overhead given that we need to use similar settings in multiple places across the application.. I am quite sure there must be a more subtle way of achieving this... still thanks for help :)

Comment: @parvkothari I have updated my answer. As you mention *use similar settings in multiple places across the application* so you can create custom menu in your app and use throughout app. I have also updated **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2hk0)**  please check.